# Semi-classical Wheeler DeWitt equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, schroedinger-equation, quantum-gravity, semiclassical

I am currently working with the Wheeler Dewitt equation and I was wondering if the following "semi-classical" limit makes sense or if something similar already exists in the literature as I would like to put it in my own work.

So the [Wheeler DeWitt equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheeler%E2%80%93DeWitt_equation) is of the form 
\begin{equation}
\hat{\mathcal{H}}\Psi =0.
\end{equation}

This equation has many problems like the one of finding in general a well defined Hilbert space for the solutions. I was wondering if, instead of considering this equation, one could first solve the non-relativistic Schrödinger equation 
\begin{equation}
i\partial_t \Psi = \hat{\mathcal{H}} \Psi
\end{equation}
with the natural Hilbert space inherited by the Schrödinger evolution and then select the states $|\Psi_G>$ such that 
\begin{equation}
<\Psi_G|\hat{\mathcal{H}}|\Psi_G>=0
\end{equation}
as approximative solutions to the real problem of solving the exact Wheeler DeWitt equation.

Comment: The classical Schrödinger Equation is defined in a Hilbert space which has nothing to do with the Hilbert space of Wheeler-DeWitt equation (this a consequence of Haag's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haag%27s_theorem) so. indeed, the $\hat{\mathcal{H}}$ is of very different nature in both cases.